# Is there any way to obtain following json result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I have a datatable

classname    Division   Subject

```
 I          A         English

 I          A         Maths

 I          B         English

 II         A         English
```

i need the output as

```
[  
   {  
      "className":I,
      Division:[  
         {  
            name:A,
            subject:[  
               {  
                  name:english
               },
               {  
                  name:maths
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            name:B,
            subject:[  
               {  
                  name:English
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "ClassName":II,
      Division:[  
         {  
            name:A,
            subject:[  
               {  
                  name:english
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Is this a relational database?

Comment: no it is not relational database

Comment: You're trying to extract this data from a file then print it out as json?

Comment: data is joined from some tables

Comment: Please consider adding more detail to your question, this is extremely vague and hard to answer.

Comment: 1) Programmatically how are you accessing this data? Data is joined from two tables that are stored in or on what? Is this this a tab delimited text file? A binary file? 2) Your JSON syntax is invalid.Enter it into http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: tables stored in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are starting with a `DataTable` like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("className");
table.Columns.Add("Division");
table.Columns.Add("Subject");
table.Rows.Add("I", "A", "English");
table.Rows.Add("I", "A", "Maths");
table.Rows.Add("I", "B", "English");
table.Rows.Add("II", "A", "English");
```

You can get the output you want like this:

```
List<DataRow> rows = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    rows.Add(row);

var result = rows.GroupBy(r => r["className"])
                 .Select(g => new
                 {
                     className = g.Key,
                     division = g.GroupBy(r => r["Division"])
                                 .Select(g1 => new
                                 {
                                     name = g1.Key,
                                     subject = g1.Select(r => new
                                                 {
                                                     name = r["Subject"]
                                                 })
                                 })
                 });

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

**Working demo**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/67mjiu

Answer (score 0):

You got two options:

1. Create the JSON by hand (using a `StringBuilder` or JSON.NETs built in object types)
2. Create DTO (Data Transfer Objects) which looks like the wanted structure, fill them with data, and then serialize them.

DTOs:

```
public class Clazz
{
    public string className { get; set; }
    public Division[] Division { get; set; }
}

public class Division
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Subject[] subject { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Your JSON is not valid. All names and string values must be escaped with quotes.